# selector syntax: why I am getting unrecognized selector error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I have a method to compare 2 objects:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSObject *)object1 to:(NSObject *)object2{
    // do some stuff
    return NSOrderedSame; // or NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending
}
```

This method gets called like this:

```
NSArray *sortedSyncedAufgaben = [syncedAufgabe sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:to:)];
```

Now, when I run this on my iPhone, a "unrecognized selector error" is thrown in the line with the selector:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ImpfVorgang compare:to:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ebf040'

What is wrong? I thought for each parameter I need a colon?

Comment: Can we see the whole error message?

Comment: Where is that method defined? On the class of which `syncedAufgabe` is an instance?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, in the same class / view controller

Comment: @NobodyNada `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ImpfVorgang compare:to:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ebf040'`

Comment: @mradlmaier Is `compare:to:` defined in ImpfVorgang.m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingSelector:` tries to apply you selector to the object on the left-hand side of the comparison, not to the class that calls `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`. In other words, if the selector exists in your class that initiates the sort, not in the class of the object inside `NSArray` (i.e. not in your `ImpfVorgang` class), you are going to see an "unrecognized selector error".

You can change your code to apply the selector manually, like this:

```
NSArray * sortedSyncedAufgaben = [syncedAufgabe sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSObject *a, NSObject* b) {
    return [self compare:a to:b];
}];
```

Alternatively, you could move the comparison logic into the comparator block, and drop the `compare:to:` method altogether.